# How to Show Value Based on Customer's Tax Zone in Acumatica Sales Order

Tags: c#, dynamic, field, acumatica

I have a field called Sales Channel where, if the customer tax zone ID is local, it should show local, else foreign. I have my DAC as a dropdown list for the moment but I need to change it to suit this requirement as a dynamic text field, how can I do this? I have attached some images for guidance.

[Need to take tax zone ID from customer screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgkci.png)

[The customer's tax zone ID determines the Sales Channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVGhE.png)

Answer (score 0):

One approach to this can be that you define a PXSetup view of the taxzone which uses the current customer as a where clause.

```
PXSetup<TaxZone, Where<TaxZone.taxZoneID, Equal<Current<Customer.taxZoneID>>>> customerTaxZone;
```

Then subscribe to the FieldUpdated Event of the customer field. Using the current value of the taxzone setup view you can then determine the value of the Sales Channel field.

Comment: All of this must be defined in the extended graph of the Sales Order according to Acumatica training I assume?

Comment: Yes, in the extension of the SOOrderEntry Graph